# Isn't this a balanced binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Isn't the tree in the image given below a balanced binary tree? One of my friends was arguing that this can't be balanced because the node A is at depth 2 from the root E and G and L are at depth 4 from E and hence E has to unbalanced by a factor of -2. My belief is that the node is only unbalanced if:
 `Absolute(Heigh of left subtree - Height of right subtree) > 1`
 The height of the left subtree of E is 3 because of D and not 2. What would be the best way to convince my friend??
[image: Balanced Tree]

Comment: You're arguing about two definitions of the word "balanced." You can't argue one is better than the other... you just have to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), it's balanced if it's the minimum possible height. In this case, you could move both leaves 'G' and 'L' to 'A', and the tree height would be 4. There is a way to make the height smaller, so the tree is not balanced.
Any tree with height `ceil(log2(n))` would be balanced.

Comment: Indeed `ceil(log2(16))+1=5` and the minimum possible height is 5. Further, if we were able to set any 15 nodes in minimum height tree we would get a perfectly balanced tree of height 4. Any node that would be added would increase the height to 5, which proves you're right ;)

Comment: Both leafs 'G' **and** 'L' can be moved to parent 'A'. Tree height will be 3.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this is a binary search tree so G and L can't be moved to A. Furthermore this is a AVL tree. As per wikipedia "The height of a node is the length of the longest downward path to a leaf from that node. The height of the root is the height of the tree." The height of node B is 2 and of node J is 3. The difference is not greater than 1 and this condition is true for every node in the tree so I believe this tree is balanced. The tree has 14 nodes and ceil(log2(14+1)) = 4 which is the height of the tree.

Comment: @SalilSurendran Then it is indeed balanced AVL tree, but not generally balanced tree.

Comment: @SalilSurendran BST with same nodes and height 3 (lisp notation): `(H (D (B (A nil nil) (C nil nil)) (F (E nil nil) (J nil nil))) (L (J (I nil nil) (K nil nil)) (M nil (N nil nil))))`

Comment: @Jarlax What is the definition of a generally balanced tree? As per what I know a tree is said to be balanced if every node in the tree is balanced? A node is said to be balanced if `Absolute(Heigh of left subtree - Height of right subtree) > 1`. Height of a tree is the longest path from that node to a leaf.

Comment: @SalilSurendran Tree is height balanced if it has minimal possible depth (maximal height). In practice that means that there is no 2 leafs with depth difference more than 1. Example of self-balancing tree with this property is red-black tree (no matter in what order you will add nodes A-N, resulting tree will have height 3). So, AVL tree is "almost" balanced BST, red-black tree - perfectly balanced BST.